# thread error in python cgi script

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, apache, cgi

I'm getting the following error on a CGI script I'm running....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py", line 908, in <module>, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
    webpage(), referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py", line 899, in webpage, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
    getResults(form), referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py", line 557, in getResults, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
    new_nums = processNums(nums), referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py", line 328, in processNums, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
    t.start(), referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 471, in start, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ()), referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
  thread.error: can't start new thread, referer: http://mysite/cgi-bin/dev/testing.py
```

It could be a ulimit issue on my machine but I wanted to check my code with you guys.  Here is the code I use for threading....

```
import Queue
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread


def processNums(nums):
    new_nums = []

    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for num in nums:
        queue.put(num)

    thread_num = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    for x in range(0,thread_num):
        t = Thread(target=multNum,args=(queue,new_nums,))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    queue.join()
    return new_nums


def multNum(queue,new_nums):
    while True:
        try: num = queue.get()
        except: break

        # do something....
        new_num = num*123456

        new_nums.append(new_num)
        queue.task_done()


print processNums([54,12,87,3268,2424,148,5,9877])
```

outputs [6666624, 1481472, 10740672, 403454208, 299257344, 18271488, 617280, 1219374912]

This is a really REALLY watered down version of my code (there is so much I cannot copy all of it here) but I suspect my problem lies here.  My question is...  Should I be closing these threads somehow?  Doesn't python do that automatically?  Or is this a configuration issue with apache or my linux server?  This is the first time I'm seeing this error, but it is also the first time I've run this application with the data set I'm using.  This data set generates thousands of threads.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Threads should be joined when you are finished with them.  See the Python documentation for [Thread.join()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

If a thread is not joined, it will remain the process table as a zombie process.

On Linux based system, pthreads are used to implement the Python threading interface.  It's likely that a call to `pthread_create` is failing.  Here are the possible reasons from the man page.  It's likely an `EAGAIN` error, but the error code is not made available through the Python threading interface.

> ```
>   EAGAIN Insufficient  resources  to create another thread, or a system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.
>           The latter case may occur in two ways: the RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via setrlimit(2)), which  limits  the
>           number  of  process  for  a  real  user  ID,  was reached; or the kernel's system-wide limit on the number of threads,
>           /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max, was reached.
>
>    EINVAL Invalid settings in attr.
>
>    EPERM  No permission to set the scheduling policy and parameters specified in attr.
> ```